# Print all possible conditions in Python

Tags: python

There are four sensors they're whether on (0) or off (1).

They all can be on or off at the same time.

Example conditions are as below:

```
A0 0
A1 0
A2 1
A3 0
```

Another one:

```
A0 1
A1 1
A2 1
A3 1
```

How can I print all possible conditions?

I'm writing a code that requires to check which condition is true to do something, and by the time I have wrote ten conditions by thinking. But I think another code can help me to have all conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`.  Example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for p in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=4):
...     for i, v in enumerate(p):
...         print(f"A{i} {v}")
...     print("----")
...
A0 0
A1 0
A2 0
A3 0
----
A0 0
A1 0
A2 0
A3 1
----
A0 0
A1 0
A2 1
A3 0
----
A0 0
A1 0
A2 1
A3 1
----
A0 0
A1 1
A2 0
A3 0
----
A0 0
A1 1
A2 0
A3 1
----
A0 0
A1 1
A2 1
A3 0
----
A0 0
A1 1
A2 1
A3 1
----
A0 1
A1 0
A2 0
A3 0
----
A0 1
A1 0
A2 0
A3 1
----
A0 1
A1 0
A2 1
A3 0
----
A0 1
A1 0
A2 1
A3 1
----
A0 1
A1 1
A2 0
A3 0
----
A0 1
A1 1
A2 0
A3 1
----
A0 1
A1 1
A2 1
A3 0
----
A0 1
A1 1
A2 1
A3 1
----
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
>>> list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=4))
```

---

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 1, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```